# removing multiple arrays from a 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

My web app is taking in arbitrarily large 2D arrays that sometimes look something like this:

```
var multiArray = [["","","",""],[1,2,3],["hello","dog","cat"],["","","",""]];
```

I want to write a function to take out every array inside of multiArray that is comprised entirely of quotes. In other words, any array that looks like this:

```
["","","",""]
```

should be deleted from multiArray.

I tried writing the following function, but the problem with using splice in a for loop is that splicing will change the length of the array, and I end up trying to access undefined elements. Please help!

Thanks!

Here's the incorrect function I wrote:

```
function cleanWhitespace(arrayOfArrays) {
    var i;
    var arrayOfArraysLength = arrayOfArrays.length;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfArraysLength; i++) {
        var cleanedArray = $.grep(arrayOfArrays[i], function(element) {
                                return element != ""
                            });
        if (cleanedArray.length == 0)  {
            arrayOfArrays.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return arrayOfArrays;
};
```

Comment: iterate in reverse, or do `i--` every time you do a `.splice()`. This is a very common issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) :

```
multiArray = $.grep(multiArray, function(v){
    return v.join('');
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scZcB/

Comment: Thank you! Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

on the fly:

```
var multiArray = [["","","",""],[1,2,3],["hello","dog","cat"],["","","",""]];
var outputArr = removeQuoteArrays(multiArray);
console.log(outputArr);

function removeQuoteArrays(arr) {
    var outputArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var currArr = arr[i];
        var isAllQuotes = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < currArr.length; j++) {
            if (currArr[j] != "") {
                isAllQuotes = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isAllQuotes) {
            outputArr.push(currArr);
        }
    }
    return outputArr;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cN9W5/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array instead.

```
// Only add if...
cleanedArray = multiArray.filter(function(arr){
    // Some elements are not blank
    return arr.some(function(e){ return e !== "" }) 
})
```

Comment: A bit more succinctly:
`var cleanedArray = multiArray.filter(function(arr){return arr.some(String)});`

Comment: That's not always possible. Sometimes there are multiple references to the original Array, which means they won't see the update.

Answer (score 0):

I added a length check to your function to break out of the loop if the index reaches the array length:

```
if (i >= arrayOfArrays.length)
      break;
```

Which makes:

```
function cleanWhitespace(arrayOfArrays) {
    var i;
    var arrayOfArraysLength = arrayOfArrays.length;
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfArraysLength; i++) {
        var cleanedArray = $.grep(arrayOfArrays[i], function(element) {
                                return element != ""
                            });
        if (cleanedArray.length == 0)  {
            arrayOfArrays.splice(i, 1);
            if (i >= arrayOfArrays.length)
                break;
        }
    }
    return arrayOfArrays;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var multiArray = [["","","",""],[1,2,3],["hello","dog","cat"],["","","",""]];

function cleanWhitespace(arrayOfArrays) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
        var emptyElements = 0;

        for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfArrays[i].length; j++ ) {
            if (arrayOfArrays[i][j] === "") {
                emptyElements++;
            }
        }

        if (emptyElements === arrayOfArrays[i].length) {
            arrayOfArrays.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    return arrayOfArrays;
}

console.log(cleanWhitespace(multiArray));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Jfr9/